# Remoteview is not applied in background

Tags: android, android-remoteview

I've applied Remoteview to notification. It works when user is in foreground, but when user is in background, notification is not showed as remoteview.

How can I apply remoteview when user is background?

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.doggy_downgrade3)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
            .setContentTitle("Doggy")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setNumber(1)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContent(remoteViews)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

The above is my code for building a notification.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set two different views, one is custom content view and the other is Big content view and set it as follows -

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setCustomContentView(contentViewSmall)
            .setCustomBigContentView(contentViewBig)
            .setContentTitle("Custom Notification")
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setWhen(when);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Also read my blog on [Custom Layouts for Push notifications](https://android.jlelse.eu/custom-layouts-for-your-push-notification-d8219d9962e)

Comment: What if I have to display the same layout no matter what?

Comment: pass the same RemoteView to both `setCustomContentView` and `setCustomBigContentView` methods of the `NotificationCompat.Builder` object.

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it's not working, btw 
 this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948772/4696610  solved my issue.